# How to Link to WP Pages Internally and Extenally

Tags: links

Converting my HTML template to WP Theme I am confused how to linkto the pages in WP?
For Example I have an Item div which I would like to link to my store page when user click on that but I dont know how to get the correct URL for my store page?!
This is also happening when I would like to link from another site to my page for example how I can link to my page from here? 
http//www.ghazalphoto.portfolio.html  Or
http//www.ghazalphoto.portfolio.php Or 
http//www.ghazalphoto.portfolio

Answer (score 0):

Use this to output correct link:

```
<?php 
   $page = get_page_by_title( 'Store' );
   echo get_permalink( $page );
?>
```

Or if you know ID of your page (you can get ID from administration), you can use just (if ID is 2)

```
<?php echo get_permalink( 2 ); ?>
```

You can read more about [get_permalink function here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

And I would also suggest you to read something about [wp_nav_menu function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) to enable your theme to use Navigation menus.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a page in wordpress it works like a template in your case to create a portfolio page you need to create a page-portfolio.php file in your theme folder.

Add on first line:

```
 <?php
 /*
 Template Name: Portfolio Page
 */
 ?>
```

Build your portfolio page here. 
Create a page in Administration-> Pages-> Add New.
Select 'Portfolio Page' from drop down on right side.
Publish and take note of the now live URL.

In WordPress you can link in the code like:

```
<a href="portfolio pages live link"<div>Link to Portfolio Page</div></a>
// or
<a href="<?php $page = get_page_by_title( 'Behseinis Page' );echo get_permalink( $page ); ?>">
<div>Link to Portfolio Page</div></a>
```